# Start serving file while converting it [PHP]

Tags: php, download, serving

i'm wondering how to serve a file while i'm converting it, to lower thhe waiting time of the client. I'v tried the chunked header in php, but only the first bytes of the file are downloaded.

```
    header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
    header('Content-Type:audio/mpeg');
    header('Connection: keep-alive');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($mp3File) . '"');

    header('Connection: close');
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    $buffer = '';
    $handle = fopen($mp3File, 'rb');
    if($handle === false){
        return false;
    }

    while(!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fread($handle, 8192);

        echo sprintf("%x\r\n", strlen($buffer));
        echo $buffer;
        echo "\r\n";

        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    echo sprintf("%x\r\n", 0);
    echo "\r\n";



    fclose($handle);
```

So i'm asking for some help here, in case some one already found some trick or whatever.